# Java valueOf method for generic class

Tags: java, generics, tostring, value-of

Given a generic class `Foo<T>`, I would like to create a static method `valueOf(String s)`. The `String s` should hold the name of a class (e.g. `"java.lang.Integer"`). A call to `valueOf("java.lang.Integer")` should then return a new object `Foo<Integer>`.

In my class (see code below), I want to store the `Class<T>`, which is passed as parameter to the constructor `Foo(Class<T> clazz)`. But in the `valueOf`-method, I am not sure what parameter to pass to the constructor `Foo(Class<T> clazz)` of the object I like to return.

Since I am relatively new to java reflections, I am unsure how I can implement this logic to my generic class. I have learned that the `Class.forName(String)` method returns an object `Class<?>`, but I don't know how to find out the type that the wildcard ? stands for (in case that's possible using reflections), or am I wrong going into this direction?

```
public class Foo<T> {
    private Class<T> clazz;
    public Foo(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public static <E> Foo<E> valueOf(String s) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(s);
        // here i am stuck. I would like to return new Foo<E>, 
        // but what is E, E's class and therefore the parameter for the constructor?
    }
}
```

Comment: "what is E, E's class and therefore the parameter for the constructor?" You already have the class in clazz variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this with generics. Generics are just casts the compiler puts in for you, statically. So, if you couldn't do this with casts you write in the code (that is, you can't have a different cast for different strings), you can't do it with generics either.

You need some sort of key instead of a `String` which conveys the type `T`/`E`. You can pass in the `Class<E>` directly:

```
    public static <E> Foo<E> valueOf(Class<E> clazz) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        // ...
    }
```